# Malformed POM: Unrecognised tag

Tags: java, xml, maven

I was trying to work on this project for school and needed to use MultiMaps from Apache.commons. I edited my `pom.xml` file to add that dependency and could use the *import* command in my IDE. But when I try to run it I get an error, it has something to do with my `pom.xml` file but I don't see any issues with it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ClassStuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>Scheduler</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</project>
```

Comment: You need to wrap your `dependency` tags in `dependencies` (and maybe `dependencyManagement`). See https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Your `<dependency></dependency>` should be contained/wrapped in a `<dependencies></dependencies>` object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your `dependency` tags in `dependencies` (and maybe `dependencyManagement`).

You can find an example and further information on `pom.xml` file structure in the official Maven documentation, e.g. here: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ClassStuff</groupId>
<artifactId>Scheduler</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```